# How do I concatenate two fields in n1ql?

Tags: nosql, couchbase

Is there a function in n1ql similar to mysql's concatenation that will allow me to concatenate two fields, such as:

```
select
firstName + " " + lastName
from table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the N1QL documentation (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringops.html):

> N1QL provides the concatenation string operator. The result of the
>   concatenation operator is also a string.
>
> ```
> expression || expression    The following example shows concatenation of two strings.
> ```
>
> **Query:**
>
> ```
> SELECT fname || " " || lname AS full_name
> FROM tutorial
> ```
>
> **Result:**
>
> ```
> {
>   "results": [
>     {
>       "full_name": "Dave Smith"
>     },
>     {
>       "full_name": "Earl Johnson"
>     },
>     {
>       "full_name": "Fred Jackson"
>     },
>     {
>       "full_name": "Harry Jackson"
>     },
>     {
>       "full_name": "Ian Taylor"
>     },
>     {
>       "full_name": "Jane Edwards"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want concatenate `Integers` should convert it first with `TO_STRING`:

```
SELECT 'My name is ' || fname  || ' and my age is ' || TO_STRING(30) || ' years old' AS age
FROM app 



{
  "results": [
    {
      "age": "My name is Dave and my age is 30 years old"
    },
    {
      "age": "My name is Earl and my age is 30 years old"
    },
    {
      "age": "My name is Fred and my age is 30 years old"
    },
    {
      "age": "My name is Harry and my age is 30 years old"
    },
    {
      "age": "My name is Ian and my age is 30 years old"
    },
    {
      "age": "My name is Jane and my age is 30 years old"
    }
  ]
}
```